# Spring Cloud - hystrix-dashboard is not working?

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix

**Spring Cloud Hystrix Circuit Breaker** Pattern Example. I have added below dependency in the code taking  **https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-cloud/spring-hystrix-circuit-breaker-tutorial/** Spring Boot Starter parent version is **1.5.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I launch **http://localhost:9098/hystrix**, nothing is coming.

Could you please guide how to fixed it ?

[image]

**Here is the code:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class SpringHystrixSchoolServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringHystrixSchoolServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have @EnableHystrixDashboard on your Application class?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `/hystrix-dashboard` ?

Comment: Make sure you have org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator as a dependency and the path is /actuator/hystrix at least with spring boot 2

Comment: https://github.com/chirdeeptomar/kotlin-spring-micro-services/tree/master/hystrix-dashboard

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using spring boot 1.3,you need to use http://localhost:9098/hystrix.html

From Spring boot 2.x hystrix URL move to http://localhost:9098/hystrix